# Choosing between strcuts, classes and enums

Tags: swift, class, struct, enums

I have some sample code I put together as I am trying to figure out how to model my first app. I'm not sure if the "shoe examples" should be enums or classes. I guess I could create one class that has all the features that each class has ( sole, string, color, fit) and then make subclasses of the main class and add the other features for classes that need them. I also thought about setting each up as enums because the data is fixed. Ultimately I want a user to be able to push a button and decide if a condition is a poor, fair, or excellent for each case in the enum or each stored property in the class or struct.

```
enum Conditions {
    case poor
    case fair
    case excellent
}

// Shoe exmaples 

enum Nike  {
    case sole
    case string
    case color
    case fit
}

struct Rebook {
    case sole
    case string
    case color
    case fit
}

enum Jordan {
    case sole
    case string
    case color
    case fit
}

enum sketchers {
    case sole
    case string
    case color
    case fit
    case (idk something else)
}

enum heels {
    case sole
    case string
    case color
    case fit
    case height
    case width
}
```

or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach is almost there. If I understand you correctly, you want each property of the shoe to be ranked with a Condition enum. You might have more luck making each shoe a generic class, like so:

```
class Shoe {
    var sole: Condition?
    var string: Condition?
    var color: Condition?
    var fit: Condition?

    init(sole: Condition, string: Condition, color: Condition, fit: Condition) {
        self.sole = sole
        self.string = string
        self.color = color
        self.fit = fit
    }
}
```

This will now allow you to create instances of `Shoe` for every type you want, instead of a different enum for each shoe. For example, if the user ranked a Nike, you might store their results like so:

```
var Nike = Shoe(sole: .poor, string: .excellent, color: .fair, fit: .excellent)
```

If you want to add different rankings for each shoe, such as "idk something else" or "height", then you can always add more properties to the `Shoe` class and make them optional, or you can subclass the `Shoe` class to add more properties.